# Can't use Gradle version 7.0.2 with java 11 on visual studio code

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

I am developing with flutter on visual studio code.
recently I upgraded gradle to 7.0.2,
and changed this section in build.gradle file accordingly:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'. <--- here
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'
}
```

than I run flutter (flutter run) and got this error:
[image]

so I upgraded java to 11 and made sure it applied with the next command: *gradlew --version*:
[image]

so supposingly, all should work, but the error above keep showing, even after restarting visual studio code - d**oes anyone have an idea what could be missing or went wrong ?**

btw:
there are other posts explaining how to fix this issue with android studio, but non for visual studio code.
thanks!

Comment: What's the advance in not using Android Studio?

Comment: I am planning to, but I also like to know why things don't work and how to fix them (:

Comment: Clean java language server workspace from Command Palette. Does the error goes away?

Comment: I know i am bit later, but i had the exact same problem. I was using vscode to develop, but i had installed Android Studio. When i run "flutter doctor -v" shows java 1.8 associated to Android Studio (i dont know where that configuration is storaged). So i uninstall AS (Actually I never use it) and then my gradle starts to recognize java 11!!!

Comment: @FrancoBerardi, Interesting I will try

Comment: @vigdora after a couple of days I installed the *latest* Android Studio version and now both apps are working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Most appropriate solution I think would be to specify the `org.gradle.java.home` variable in gradle.properties file. Do it like this:

```
org.gradle.java.home=Path_to_jdk
```

Make sure not to put any quotation marks before and after the path.

An alternate solution would be, assuming that other devs have `java.exe` set in their `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` variable (Note: `JAVA_HOME` points to the JDK installation directory, and NOT the bin directory), leaving the gradle.properties as it is.

Comment: This seems to solve the main issue, but I don't want to have hard coded path to java jdk in this file, as each developer might have different path - how can I solve holisticly?

Comment: Edited the answer. I think it should do.

Comment: When I type `$JAVA_HOME` in visual studio code terminal I get:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home`
BUT yet without explicitly adding it to `org.gradle.java.home` as you suggested - it doesn't work

Comment: You don't have to add it to JAVA_HOME now. Make sure that it doesn't point to the bin directory. You can also try it by pointing the bin directory to the PATH variable.

Comment: Don't add \bin at the end

Comment: as you can see on my previous comment,  my $JAVA_HOME is not pointing to the bin directory, it points to the home.

Comment: You can try the PATH variable also, and have you removed the org.gradle.java.home from your gradle.properties?

Comment: yes, I removed the org.gradle.java.home, btw, after installing "java extension Pack for java"  for vsCode, all seems to work now (as I mentioned in the solution) I am curious to know why.

Comment: I will try adding the to PATH as well, will see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle`, set

```
sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'
```

After it's rebuilt successfully,`clean java language server workspace` from Command Palette then reload window. See if the question goes away.

Comment: that didn't work,  also I dont find the command you mentioned in the Command Palette - I am using flutter as my workspace.@JustingCoding answer above did helped. I am thinking out loud - may be your solution refer to compiling android app's code , while I refer to the jdk gradle uses to builds itself...